# Holder condition on $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k \cos(b^k x)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm struggling with solving the following problem.

Let $0<a<1$ and $2\leq b \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $b$ is an integer. Prove that the following series
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k \cos(b^k x)
\end{align}
defines a function from $C^\alpha[-\pi,\pi]$ where $0<\alpha<1$ if $ab=1$.

First I proved the uniform convergence of this series. Using the absolute convergence and geometric series, we have
\begin{align}
\left\vert \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k \cos(b^k x) \right\vert \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \vert a^k \cos(b^k x) \vert \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k = \frac{1}{1-a} < \infty,
\end{align}
hence the series is uniformly convergent. Therefore, we can express
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k \cos(b^k x) - \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k \cos(b^k y) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k \left( \cos(b^k x) - \cos(b^k y) \right).
\end{align}
Assume that $x<y$ and $\vert x-y \vert < 1$, and then for each $k$, we have
\begin{align}
\vert \cos(b^k x) - \cos(b^k y) \vert \leq C \vert x-y \vert \vert \sin (b^k x_0) \vert \leq C \vert x-y \vert^\alpha,
\end{align}
for some $C>0$ and $x_0\in[x,y]$ by the mean value property. We don't have to consider the case $\vert x-y \vert \geq 1$ since $\vert x-y \vert$ is at most $2\pi$. So summing up all these so far,
\begin{align}
\left\vert \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k \left( \cos(b^k x) - \cos(b^k y) \right) \right\vert \leq \frac{C}{1-a} \vert x-y \vert^\alpha.
\end{align}
Does this complete the proof?

Comment: why is $\begin{align}
\vert \cos(b^k x) - \cos(b^k y) \vert \leq C \vert x-y \vert \vert \sin (b^k x_0) \vert \leq C \vert x-y \vert^\alpha
\end{align}$ true? the derivative depends on $k$ as it is $-b^k \sin$ so $C$ depends on $k$; I think that here you need to split the sum depending on how small $x-y$ is wr to $1/b^k=a^k$ and use the trivial inequality for $k$ large enough so $a^k << |x-y|$ and the mean value only for $k$ small so $|x-y| << a^k$

Comment: @Conrad You're totally right.  I was suspicious and posted the OP because I did not use the clue $ab=1$ at all in the procedure, and it was my mistake. I will post the answer according to the hint you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I resolve the OP and post this answer. As mentioned in the OP, we just consider the case $\vert x-y \vert <1$. For a given $h=\vert x-y \vert$, there is $0<k_0\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^{k_0+1} \leq \vert x-y \vert < 1/b^{k_0}=a^{k_0}$ by Archimedean property. Then we have
\begin{align}
\left\vert \sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k(\cos(b^k x) - \cos(b^k y)) \right\vert &\leq \left\vert \sum_{k\leq k_0} a^k(\cos(b^k x) - \cos(b^k y)) \right\vert + \left\vert \sum_{k>k_0} a^k(\cos(b^k x) - \cos(b^k y)) \right\vert \\
&\leq C\sum_{k\leq k_0} \vert x-y \vert + 2\sum_{k>k_0}a^k \\
&\leq C_1\vert x-y \vert^\alpha + C_2 a^{k_0+1} \leq Ch^\alpha,
\end{align}
using the mean value property for the first sum and the geometric series for the second sum. This completes the proof.